# Flutter - Size of Transform.scale widget does not change when its child is scaled

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a widget `A` that I want to scale (pixel perfect). Depending on display width of the device, the size of `A` should be either increased or decreased. I tried the `Transform.scale` widget to change the size of the `A`. This works well but the size of the `Transform.scale` widget never changes. It always matches the original size of `A` (without scaling). 
Is there any way to force `Transform.scale` that it always adopts the size of its child? Or is there an alternative approach?

You can find an image here that shows the current and the required situation

**EDIT:**
Widget `A` and its children should shrink/grow uniformly. The ratios between them should not change.

[image]

Here is the code I currently tried

```
_buildWidgetA(scalingFactor) {
  return Transform.scale(
    scale: scalingFactor,
    child: A(),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Thanks to the input from @LOfG I learned that you cannot achieve the desired behavior with `Transform.scale` widget. Unfortunately, this widget does not change its size to match the dimensions of the scaled child but will always keep the width and height of the original, unscaled child.

I found another widget, `FittedBox`, with which I got the desired behavior. When using `FittedBox`, you do not define a scaling factor as you would do with `Transform.scale`. You rather put `FittedBox` inside a `Container` and define its width or height or both. The child of `FittedBox` is then scaled to match the parent `Container`.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html

```
_buildWidgetA(width, height) {
    return Container(
        width: width,
        height: height,
        child: FittedBox(
            child: A(),
        ),
    );
}
```

Comment: I spend a hours on this. Fitted box is what I need :D

Answer (score 1):

To scale a widget based on the width of the device you can use Media Query to change the scale:

First Approach:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width; //getting the current width

  return Scaffold(
    body: Transform.scale(
      scale: width <= 420 ? 0.5 : 0.8,
      child: Align(
        child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          width: 420,
          height: 420,
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Text('Example', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),),
        ),
      ),
    )
  );
}
```

Second Approach:

```
Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    width: width * 0.5,
    height: width * 0.5,
    color: Colors.green,
    child: Text(
      'Example Text',
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: width * 0.1,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thx for your suggention. However, in this case the content of the container would not scale properly. For example, font-size of any text-widgets would stay the same. I need a way to shrink/grow the widget and all its children uniformly.

Comment: Thx for the update. This is the approach that I've already tried. The child widget (in your case the Container) is scaling properly but the Transform.scale widget does not change its size. Width and height always match the dimensions of the orginal, unscaled child. Any ideas to change that?

Comment: Now i understand what you want to achieve. In your case i think the second Approach is the best, i can't find a way to make the Transform.scale change it's size.

Comment: Thx for the feedback. I was thinking about your second approach to manually scale the child widget. Unfortunately, I have tens of nested widgets that have to be rescaled as well which becomes very tedious and hard to maintain. But I found another widget that provides a similar behavior: FittedBox. I posted an answer with the details.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to change the height from the child, you could do something like:

```dart
SizeTransition(
                      sizeFactor: const AlwaysStoppedAnimation<double>(0.8),
                      child: Transform.scale(
                        scale: 0.8,
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: yourWidget,
                      ),
                    )
```