# Flutter: Prevent wrapped text when scaling down

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a widget: `HtmlWidget('<font size="200">Some Long Sentence Alright</font>')` (custom widget from https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_widget_from_html_core, but using `Text('Some Long Sentence Alright', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 200))` has the same issue).

Because it's big and long, when displayed on the phone, it wraps to:

```
Some Long 
Sentence Alright
```

There are two ways to scale it down:

**1. Transform.scale**

```
Transform.scale(
  child: myWidget,
  scale: 0.5,
)
```

Problems with this approach:

- The text is still wrapped (maybe because it's laid out, then scaled down)
- There's "phantom" margin (see [Flutter - Size of Transform.scale widget does not change when its child is scaled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61616795))

**2. FittedBox**

```
Container(
  child: FittedBox(child: myWidget),
  width: 300,
  height: 100,
)
```

There's only one problem with this approach: I don't know the expected `width/height`.

Basically, I want a widget that can scale down `myWidget` **based on scale** (like `Transform.scale`) but **does not wrap** the content (like `FittedBox`).

How do I do that?

Comment: Once you solve this, aren't you concerned that this will be scaled down so far as to be unreadable on some devices?

Comment: @Nagual As I mentioned above, `FittedBox` is what I want, but it doesn't accept scale.

Comment: @CurtEckhart That will be another problem :)

Comment: @wiradikusuma - Read through my answer. It will scale down based on layout without wrapping. The size is provided by its ancestor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Transform` widget passes its own constraints down to the `Text` widget, if the viewport is not wide enough for the 200px font size, it will be wrapped **before** scaling down on painting. See `RenderTransform` source code [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/18116933e77adc82f80866c928266a5b4f1ed645/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart#L2198): it extends `RenderProxyBox`, uses the default `performLayout` and only overrides `paint`.

Knowing that, you can implement your own `RenderObject` to transform both the constraints (during layout) and the canvas (during painting). I have come up with a simple implementation [here](https://dartpad.dev/ebf865c1cbfe4fe2dadee6a8bd6b534f). As you can see below: it works with x2, x4 and x8 the font size and there is no "phantom margin".

[image: dartpad demo]

The most important bits are here:

```dart
  @override
  void performLayout() {
    // ...

    // adjust the constraints width before performing child layout
    final childConstraints =
        constraints.copyWith(maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth / scale);

    // ...
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    // scale down during painting to compensate
    layer = context.pushTransform(/* ... */);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

FittedBox has a default fit : BoxFit.contain. Change it to what you need.

```
FittedBox(
   fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
   child: Text(
      text.pasDeven,

   ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a new approach . you can try this way and change the size of text in the html with regex

```
main() async {

  String html =
  '''
  <font size="60">Some Long Sentence Alright</font>
  ''';
  html = html.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'font size=\"?(\d{1,2})\"'), (match) {
    print(match);
    print(match.group(0));
    print(match.group(1));
    var value = int.parse(match.group(1) ?? "");
    var newValue = value ~/ 2;
    print(newValue);
    print(match.group(0)!.replaceAll(value.toString(), newValue.toString()));
    var replace = match.group(0)!.replaceAll(value.toString(), newValue.toString());
    return replace;
  });
  print(html);
}
```

the output

```
I/flutter (21629): Instance of '_RegExpMatch'
I/flutter (21629): font size="60"
I/flutter (21629): 60
I/flutter (21629): 30
I/flutter (21629): font size="30"
I/flutter (21629):   <font size="30">Some Long Sentence Alright</font>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more code in context, I can only offer a possible solution.

You can use LayoutBuilder to obtain the runtime size of the effective bounding box of the immediate ancestor widget.

I only put the snippet inside of a 680x680 Container due to lack of a better understanding of your layout context. LayoutBuilder will calculate the constraints of its immediate ancestor's bounding box and expose them for you to use at runtime.

```
Container(
          height: 680,
          width: 680,
          color: Colors.blueGrey,
          child: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {

            return Container(
               width: constraints.maxWidth,
               height: constraints.maxHeight,
               child: FittedBox(
                 fit: BoxFit.contain,
                 child: myWidget,
               );
            }
          ),
        );
```

Comment: If @mario-francois answer works, it should be the accepted answer if for no other reason than its simplicity. You should try that first.

Comment: Isn't this the same as point #2 of my question? It's missing the ability to size based on scale.

Comment: Not the same. You said your issue was that you didn't know the expected width/height. LayoutBuilder gives those values to you at runtime. LayoutBuilder() is the point of my solution. The rest you know.

Comment: What I need to know is the dimension of `myWidget`. Basically, I want to say, e.g., "Draw `myWidget` at 50% of *its* size". `LayoutBuilder` is to get the dimension of its container (so you can size the child accordingly), not its child, I think?

Comment: Boxfit.contain says “expand this child to ‘my dimensions’”. By wrapping fittedBox inside of some container you know the size of, you have total control over the size of the child. Have you tried any of the suggested answers (not just mine) ? Seems like you have been offered several methods to get the effect you’re seeking. Let us know if you succeed and which technique you ended up using.

Comment: Please look at the accepted answer, it seems we have to go lower level.